# How can I avoid underflow in my computation?

Tags: numerics

I have the following code:

```
n = 11; 
λ[0] = 1; 
α[0] = 10; 
If[n != 9, Do[Delt[L] = 0; , {L, 0, n}]]; 
Delt[9] = 1; 
Do[
  λ[τ + 1] = λ[0] + Sum[λ[k]*((11^α[k]*(10 - λ[k]))/(11^α[k] + 1) - 0.2), {k, 0, τ}];
  α[τ + 1] = α[0] + Sum[5*Delt[k], {k, 0, τ}] - Sum[α[k]/2^λ[k], {k, 0, τ}];,
  {τ, 0, n}
]

Information["λ", LongForm -> False]
Information["α", LongForm -> False]
```

For `n = 20` I have the following message:

> Underflow occurred in computation

I want to do the calculation for `n = 20` or even `n = 30` without  underflow occurring. Any suggestions?

Comment: From help: `represents a number too small to represent explicitly on your computer system.`  so one way is not to make your numbers that small?
 see also [How to avoid overflow or underflow in mathematica?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/7OAxJINJOfk) and

Comment: @Nasser Dear  Nasser, I reviewed that. But I can not use for my code.

Comment: Is there any chance that you might be able to express λ[τ+1] and α[τ+1] strictly in terms of λ[τ] and α[τ]? If that could be done simply enough and without using decimal approximations then RSolve might give you closed form solutions for λ[n] and α[n].

Comment: @Bill λ[τ+1] and α[τ+1] are related. Can I use of `RSolve`?

Comment: RSolve can handle some, sometimes simple, systems of recurrence relations. Look in the help page, click on Scope and scroll down to see that they show systems of recurrence relations that depend on each other. I suspect the key is to think about the algebra to simplify your system as I described.

Comment: @Bill I help of your suggestion, an write the following code:`RSolve[{\[Lambda][\[Tau] + 1] == \[Lambda][0] + 
    Sum[\[Lambda][
       k]*((11^\[Alpha][k]*(10 - \[Lambda][k]))/(11^\[Alpha][k] + 
           1) - 2/10), {k, 0, \[Tau]}], 
     \[Alpha][\[Tau] + 1] == \[Alpha][0] + 
    Sum[5*Delt[k], {k, 0, \[Tau]}] - 
    Sum[\[Alpha][k]/2^\[Lambda][k], {k, 0, \[Tau]}], \[Lambda][0] == 
   1, \[Alpha][0] == 
   10}, {\[Lambda][\[Tau]], \[Alpha][\[Tau]]}, \[Tau]]`, but I can not gain output.

Comment: @Bill Can I have your suggestion on this question?

Comment: As I suggested, I think you need to see if you can simplify your recurrence for λ[τ+1] and α[τ+1] to depend only on λ[τ] and α[τ] and not on a summation of all prior λ[k] and α[k]. Even then the recurrence may not be simple enough for RSolve to find a closed form solution. The sudden change with Delt[9] may also complicate this.

Comment: @Bill Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `0.2`, an approximate machine number, to `2/10`, an exact rational. Exact calculations don't underflow.

Unfortunately, the results, while exact, are unwieldy.